# Drawing your own Graphic in Java with Graphics2d

Tags: java

I have been trying very hard these past days to understand Graphics2d. I do understand the shapes an all, however I can not draw a simple Graph with it.

My Goal is to draw a Coordinate System, that you can change its length if you want to. Like you say the min x Value would be -5 and the max x Value would be 10 and it would scale it self to it and the function too. However I have a really big Problem just creating and scaling the axis correctly. I think this just comes from a high not understanding everything correctly. This is why I  would be glad if someone could help me with this matter.

Here is the code I have been working on. It is absolutely not finished. However I would like to get the scaling and all right. But ever other correction is gladly welcomed, due to me being a newbie in java.
I also tried to make it that if like min x would be positive there would be no x axis. Which just does not work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

public class GraphPlotter extends JFrame {
    //f(x) = ax² + bx + c

    //Knöpfe
    private JButton _ploten = new JButton("Plot");
    private JButton _limits = new JButton("Limits");

    //Text
    private JLabel _funk = new JLabel("f(x) =");
    private JLabel _x2 = new JLabel("x² +");
    private JLabel _x = new JLabel("x +");
    private JLabel _xmin = new JLabel("X min");
    private JLabel _ymin = new JLabel("Y min");
    private JLabel _ymax = new JLabel("Y max");
    private JLabel _xmax = new JLabel("X max");

    private String _nummber = "0";

    //Textfelder
    private JTextField _a = new JTextField(_nummber, 3);
    private JTextField _b = new JTextField(_nummber, 3);
    private JTextField _c = new JTextField(_nummber, 3);
    private JTextField _xMinField = new JTextField("-10");
    private JTextField _xMaxField = new JTextField("10");
    private JTextField _yMinField = new JTextField("-10");
    private JTextField _yMaxField = new JTextField("10");

    //Felder
    private JPanel _top = new JPanel();
    private JPanel _zoom = new JPanel();
    private JPanel _graph = new Graph();

    public GraphPlotter() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setTitle("Graph Plotter");

    //Alignment
        _funk.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        _x2.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        _x.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        _ploten.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        _a.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        _b.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        _c.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    //So if you click on the TextField that it marks it
        _a.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                _a.setSelectionStart(0);
                _a.setSelectionEnd(_a.getText().length());
            }
        });
        _b.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                _b.setSelectionStart(0);
                _b.setSelectionEnd(_b.getText().length());
            }
        });
        _c.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                _c.setSelectionStart(0);
                _c.setSelectionEnd(_c.getText().length());
            }
        });
        _xMinField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                _xMinField.setSelectionStart(0);
                _xMinField.setSelectionEnd(_xMinField.getText().length());
            }
        });
        _xMaxField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                _xMaxField.setSelectionStart(0);
                _xMaxField.setSelectionEnd(_xMaxField.getText().length());
            }
        });
        _yMinField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                _yMinField.setSelectionStart(0);
                _yMinField.setSelectionEnd(_yMinField.getText().length());
            }
        });
        _yMaxField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                _yMaxField.setSelectionStart(0);
                _yMaxField.setSelectionEnd(_yMaxField.getText().length());
            }
        });


    //Aktions for the buttons
        _ploten.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //draw a new function
            }
        });
        _limits.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //reskale the Graph
            }
        });

    //Layouts
        //Main
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;        
        c.ipady = 20;       
        c.gridwidth = 3;    
        c.gridx = 0;        
        c.gridy = 0;        
        add(_top, c);

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;                   
        c.weightx = 1.0;      
        c.gridwidth = 2;      
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        add(_graph, c);
        
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;       
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;               
        c.weightx = 0.0;      
        c.weighty = 0.5;      
        c.ipadx = 20;           
        c.gridwidth = 1;        
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        add(_zoom, c);

        //Skalling
        _zoom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(_zoom, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    //Borders to better see the layout
        _top.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(5.0f)));
        _graph.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(5.0f)));
        _zoom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(5.0f)));
        
        _top.add(_funk);
        _top.add(_a);
        _top.add(_x2);
        _top.add(_b);
        _top.add(_x);
        _top.add(_c);
        _top.add(_ploten);

        _zoom.add(_xmin);
        _zoom.add(_xMinField);
        _zoom.add(_xmax);
        _zoom.add(_xMaxField);
        _zoom.add(_ymin);
        _zoom.add(_yMinField);
        _zoom.add(_ymax);
        _zoom.add(_yMaxField);
        _zoom.add(_limits);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Graph extends JPanel  {
        Color[] _color = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK};
        int c = 0;

        int _width;
        int _hight;
        int _diffX;
        int _diffY;
        int _midx;
        int _midy;
        int xMAX;
        int xMIN;
        int yMAX;
        int yMIN;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            _width = getWidth();
            _hight = getHeight();

            //Max und Min
            xMAX = Integer.parseInt(_xMaxField.getText());
            xMIN = Integer.parseInt(_xMinField.getText());
            yMAX = Integer.parseInt(_yMaxField.getText());
            yMIN = Integer.parseInt(_yMinField.getText());

            //Diff
            _diffX = xMAX + xMIN;
            _diffY = yMAX + yMIN;
            
            if (!(xMIN > 0) && !(xMAX < 0)) {
                _midx = (_width / 2) - _diffX;
            } else {
                _midx = 0;
            }
            if (!(yMIN > 0) && !(yMAX < 0)) {
                _midy = (_hight /2) - _diffY;
            } else {
                _midy = 0;
            }

            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            drawAxis(g2D);
        }

        private void drawAxis(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

            //X-Achse
            if (!(xMIN > 0) && !(xMAX < 0)) {
                g2d.drawLine(0, _midy, _width, _midy);
            }

            //Y-Achse
            if (!(yMIN > 0) && !(yMAX < 0)) {
                g2d.drawLine(_midx, 0, _midx, _hight);
            }

            //Scales drawing
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
            for (int n = 0; n < _width; n = n + 5) {
                g2d.drawLine(n + _midx, _midy, n + _midx, _midy + 5);
                g2d.drawLine(n - _midx, _midy, n - _midx, _midy + 5);
            }
            for (int n = 0; n < _hight; n = n +5) {
                g2d.drawLine(_midx, n + _midy, _midx - 5, n + _midy);
                g2d.drawLine(_midx, n - _midy, _midx - 5, n - _midy);
            }
        }

        private void drawGraph(Graphics2D g2d) {
            if (!(Integer.parseInt(_a.getText()) == 0) && !(Integer.parseInt(_b.getText()) == 0) && !(Integer.parseInt(_c.getText())== 0)) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Not sure what you try to do with the scales drawing. Do you want to draw them like integer steps apart in the function's input space. If so, don't increment by 5, but increment by `width / (maxX - minX)`, assuming the minX starts at 0 pixels and maxX ends at the width of the panel's drawing surface.

Comment: Consider using AffineTransform to separate model and view. It will help you with zooming and pans to.

Comment: I copied the OP's code into my IDE.  After adding a main method, I was able to actually see the GUI.  The purpose of the GUI is to plot a quadratic equation, which the OP didn't mention.  You don't need to ask the user for Y limits, unless you plan on clipping the graph.  You can calculate the Y limits from the X limits.  You extend `JFrame`, which you don't need.  You can use a `JFrame`.  Your two classes are doing too much work.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.  Your `paintComponent` method should paint the contents of your application model.  Period.  The [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern helps you to focus on one part of the application at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

I reworked your GUI.  Here's what it looks like now.

[image]

I move the X and Y axis around so that the graph fits in the drawing area.  The minimum and maximum V values are no less than -10 and 10, respectively.  I show the calculated Y minimum and maximum values in the entry panel.  The X axis and Y axis are not to the same scale.

## Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern helps me to separate my concerns and focus on one small part of the application at a time.

The application model for a Swing GUI consists of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.

The view consists of one and only one `JFrame` and as many `JPanels` as I need to create the GUI.  You can nest multiple simple `JPanels` to create a complex layout.

The controller consists of one or more `Actions` or `Listeners`.  There's usually not one controller to "rule them all".  Each `Action` or `Listener` is responsible for its part of the model and view.

I didn't write all the code at once.  I wrote a little and tested a lot.  I probably ran 150 - 200 tests of the GUI before I was satisfied.

### Model

I created one plain Java getter/setter class, the `GraphPlotterModel` class.  This class holds the X and Y minimum and maximum values, and a `java.util.List` of `Point2D` instances that make up the graph.  I also define a starting `Dimension` in pixels for the drawing `JPanel`.  The dimensions of the drawing `JPanel` can change.  One way is to maximize the GUI.

The model also holds the calculation of the quadratic equation.  I go from the X minimum to the X maximum, calculating the corresponding Y value.  The X and Y values are in units.

### View

I started the GUI with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` from the creation of the `JPanels`.  This allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one small part of the application at a time.  The top `JPanel` is made up of two individual `JPanels`, one for the title and one for the entry fields.  The center `JPanel` is a standard drawing panel.

Generally, you define Swing components on a `JPanel` in column, row order.  This makes the code easier to read and understand.

The drawing panel has a method to convert units to pixels.  This method probably took 1/3 of my total development time.  The biggest hurdle is that a standard graph goes up from the Y minimum to the Y maximum and the Y pixels go from top to bottom.  I basically use ratios to calculate the pixels.

### Controller

There's only one `JButton`, so there's only one `ActionListener`.  I made it a separate private class because it has a lot of code and I didn't want to have to pass 5 input fields to a separate class.  I check to make sure all the inputs are valid `double` values, but I didn't display any error message.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional public classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GraphPlotter implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GraphPlotter());
    }

    private final GraphPlotterModel model;

    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private JTextField aField, bField, cField;
    private JTextField xMinField, xMaxField, yMinField, yMaxField;

    public GraphPlotter() {
        this.model = new GraphPlotterModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph Plotter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createEntryPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createEntryPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(16f);
        Font titleFont = panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24f);

        JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        titlePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel(
                "Plot the quadratic equation f(x) = ax² + bx + c");
        label.setFont(titleFont);
        titlePanel.add(label);

        JPanel entryPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        entryPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        label = new JLabel("f(x) =");
        label.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(label);

        aField = new JTextField(5);
        aField.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(aField);

        label = new JLabel("x² +");
        label.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(label);

        bField = new JTextField(5);
        bField.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(bField);

        label = new JLabel("x +");
        label.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(label);

        cField = new JTextField(5);
        cField.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(cField);

        entryPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        label = new JLabel("X min:");
        label.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(label);

        xMinField = new JTextField(5);
        xMinField.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(xMinField);

        label = new JLabel("X max:");
        label.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(label);

        xMaxField = new JTextField(5);
        xMaxField.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(xMaxField);

        label = new JLabel("Y min:");
        label.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(label);

        yMinField = new JTextField(5);
        yMinField.setEditable(false);
        yMinField.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(yMinField);

        label = new JLabel("Y max:");
        label.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(label);

        yMaxField = new JTextField(5);
        yMaxField.setEditable(false);
        yMaxField.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(yMaxField);

        entryPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));

        JButton button = new JButton("Plot");
        button.addActionListener(new PlotListener());
        button.setFont(font);
        entryPanel.add(button);

        updateEntryPanel();

        panel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(entryPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return panel;
    }

    public void updateEntryPanel() {
        String formatter = "%.2f";
        aField.setText(String.format(formatter, model.getA()));
        bField.setText(String.format(formatter, model.getB()));
        cField.setText(String.format(formatter, model.getC()));
        xMinField.setText(String.format(formatter, model.getxMin()));
        xMaxField.setText(String.format(formatter, model.getxMax()));
        yMinField.setText(String.format(formatter, model.getyMin()));
        yMaxField.setText(String.format(formatter, model.getyMax()));
    }

    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final int margin;

        private final GraphPlotterModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(GraphPlotterModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.margin = 20;
            this.setPreferredSize(model.getDrawingAreaDimension());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));

            int width = getWidth() - margin - margin;
            int height = getHeight() - margin - margin;
            double xMin = model.getxMin();
            double xMax = model.getxMax();
            double yMin = model.getyMin();
            double yMax = model.getyMax();

            // Draw X Axis
            Point2D a = new Point2D.Double(xMin, 0.0);
            Point2D b = new Point2D.Double(xMax, 0.0);
            Point startPoint = toPixels(a, width, height);
            Point endPoint = toPixels(b, width, height);
            g2d.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

            // Draw Y axis
            a = new Point2D.Double(0.0, yMin);
            b = new Point2D.Double(0.0, yMax);
            startPoint = toPixels(a, width, height);
            endPoint = toPixels(b, width, height);
            g2d.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

            // Draw graph
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            Point previousPoint = null;

            List<Point2D> points = model.getPoints();
            for (Point2D point : points) {
                Point drawPoint = toPixels(point, width, height);
//              System.out.println(point + " " + drawPoint);
                if (previousPoint != null) {
                    g2d.drawLine(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y, drawPoint.x,
                            drawPoint.y);
                }
                previousPoint = (Point) drawPoint.clone();
            }
        }

        private Point toPixels(Point2D point, int width, int height) {
            double xMin = model.getxMin();
            double xMax = model.getxMax();
            double yMin = model.getyMin();
            double yMax = model.getyMax();
//          System.out.println(yMin + " " + yMax);
            double xDelta = (xMax - xMin) / width;
            double yDelta = (yMax - yMin) / height;
            double xx = Math.round((point.getX() - xMin) / xDelta);
            double yy = Math.round((point.getY() - yMin) / yDelta);
            // X in pixels goes from left to right
            int x = (int) xx + margin;
            // Y in pixels goes from top to bottom
            int y = height - (int) yy + margin;
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
    }

    private class PlotListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String aString = aField.getText().trim();
            String bString = bField.getText().trim();
            String cString = cField.getText().trim();
            String xMinString = xMinField.getText().trim();
            String xMaxString = xMaxField.getText().trim();

            double a = valueOf(aString);
            if (a == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
                return;
            }

            double b = valueOf(bString);
            if (b == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
                return;
            }

            double c = valueOf(cString);
            if (c == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
                return;
            }

            double xMin = valueOf(xMinString);
            if (xMin == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
                return;
            }

            double xMax = valueOf(xMaxString);
            if (xMax == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
                return;
            }

            model.setA(a);
            model.setB(b);
            model.setC(c);
            model.setxMin(xMin);
            model.setxMax(xMax);
            model.calculatePlot();

            updateEntryPanel();
            repaint();
        }

        private double valueOf(String s) {
            try {
                return Double.valueOf(s);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return Double.MIN_VALUE;
            }
        }

    }

    public class GraphPlotterModel {

        /** f(x) = ax² + bx + c */
        private double a, b, c, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;

        private final List<Point2D> points;

        private final Dimension drawingAreaDimension;

        public GraphPlotterModel() {
            this.drawingAreaDimension = new Dimension(500, 500);
            this.points = new ArrayList<>();
            this.xMin = -10.0;
            this.xMax = 10.0;
            this.yMin = -10.0;
            this.yMax = 10.0;
        }

        public void calculatePlot() {
            // steps should be an even number
            int steps = 100;
            double xDelta = (xMax - xMin) / steps;
            double x = xMin;
            double yMin = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            double yMax = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            points.clear();

            for (int index = 0; index <= steps; index++) {
                double y = a * x * x + b * x + c;
                Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
                points.add(point);
                x += xDelta;
                yMax = Math.max(yMax, y);
                yMin = Math.min(yMin, y);
            }

            // Make sure that Y goes from -10 to 10 at a minimum
            this.yMax = Math.max(yMax, 10.0);
            this.yMin = Math.min(yMin, -10.0);
        }

        public Dimension getDrawingAreaDimension() {
            return drawingAreaDimension;
        }

        public double getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(double a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public double getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setB(double b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public double getC() {
            return c;
        }

        public void setC(double c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public double getxMin() {
            return xMin;
        }

        public void setxMin(double xMin) {
            this.xMin = xMin;
        }

        public double getxMax() {
            return xMax;
        }

        public void setxMax(double xMax) {
            this.xMax = xMax;
        }

        public List<Point2D> getPoints() {
            return points;
        }

        public double getyMin() {
            return yMin;
        }

        public double getyMax() {
            return yMax;
        }

    }

}
```